# Upgrade from Kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 fails at 65%

Tags: upgrade, login

Upgrade from kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 abort at 65%. When I restart and try to log in show this: unable to launch "gnome-session --session=cairo-dock" X session --- "gnome-session --session=cairo-dock" not found; falling back to default session.

What can I do? I'm thinking of installing Kubuntu 14.04 from a USB.

Answer (score 0):

My upgrade from Kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 broke as well, but after the reboot.  Grub wouldn't boot.  Reposting below.  This was the only operating system on the disk also.  I don't use the cairo-dock though.  I suppose you could uninstall cairo-dock, reboot and see if it boots normally,  and restart the upgrade, then install cairo-dock if the upgrades completes successful.

worst upgrade I have gone through (13.10 to 14.04). Upgrade portion before reboot went fine. After it restarted, it broke grub, wouldn't boot. Had to go through the following steps to rebuild grub from a 13.10 LiveCD; This was in VirtualBox 4.3.10 r93012 VM.

Note: use spaces before and after "&&". For some reason this post wouldn't insert the spaces

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev && sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install /dev/sda

grub-install --recheck /dev/sda

update-grub

exit && sudo umount /mnt/dev && sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts && sudo umount /mnt/proc && sudo umount /mnt/sys && sudo umount /mnt

then had to re-enable PPA's through "Software and Updates">Other Software and clamtk's ppa can't be found.

Comment: This time didn´t have to do a grub rescue. But when Kubuntu 14.04 shows log in screen, I input the pass, press enter and appears the window saying unable to launch "gnome-session --session=cairo-dock" X session --- "gnome-session --session=cairo-dock" not found; falling back to default session.